# Jasypt and .war deployment issue: jasypt.encryptor.password missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

I am trying to deploy my SpringBoot .war to tomcat but it fails due to:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.mail.password' to java.lang.String:

Reason: Required Encryption configuration property missing: 
jasypt.encryptor.password
```

Where do I specify my encryptor password while making a package? At the moment I'm creating a package like this: clean package "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=MyEncryptionPassword" but it won't work.

Comment: you can call  System.setProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password", "password") from your application code

Comment: Always make sure that your question title is as precise as possible. I was ready to downvote expecting some kind of debugging related question.